# Python: Using def in a factorial program

Tags: factorial, python-3.4, function

So i am trying to make a program that finds the factorial using def.

changing this:

```
print ("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0: ")
x = int(input())

f = 1
for n in range(2, x + 1):
    f = f * n
print(x,' factorial is ',f)
```

to

something that uses def.

maybe

```
def intro()
    blah blah
def main()
    blah
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking. As I understand your question, you want to refactor your script so that the calculation of the factorial is a function. If so, just try this:

```
def factorial(x):             # define factorial as a function
    f = 1
    for n in range(2, x + 1):
        f = f * n
    return f

def main():                   # define another function for user input
    x = int(input("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0: "))
    f = factorial(x)          # call your factorial function
    print(x,'factorial is',f)

if __name__ == "__main__":    # not executed when imported in another script
    main()                    # call your main function
```

This will define a `factorial` function and a `main` function. The `if` block at the bottom will execute the `main` function, but only if the script is interpreted directly:

```
~> python3 test.py 
Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0: 4
4 factorial is 24
```

Alternatively, you can `import` your script into another script or an interactive session. This way it will not execute the `main` function, but you can call both functions as you like.

```
~> python3
>>> import test
>>> test.factorial(4)
24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    def factorial(n):            # Define a function and passing a parameter
        fact = 1                 # Declare a variable fact and set the initial value=1 
        for i in range(1,n+1,1): # Using loop for iteration
            fact = fact*i            
        print(fact)              # Print the value of fact(You can also use "return")

factorial(n) // Calling the function and passing the parameter
```

You can pass any number to n for getting factorial